# rails 3 using iso-8859-1 entire project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need a project in Rails 3 that is written in iso-8859-1 encoding.
The problem is my views. If I put some latin signal in them, it display like a black "?".
To solve I have to put #encoding: iso-8859-1 in each view file.

There is a way to tell all the project will be iso-8859-1?

I already try to change Application.rb file, but no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying this in `config/application.rb` (perhaps you tried `config.encoding` before—see side note)

```
config.action_controller.default_charset = 'ISO-8859-1'
```

That should work in both Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9.

Also **make sure your HTML layout is synchronized**:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

Side note: You should probably leave `config.encoding = 'UTF-8'` alone. This is especially true for Ruby 1.8, where `config.encoding` is used to set `$KCODE` and doesn't like `$KCODE = 'NONE'`, which is what you would have to put for ISO-8859-1.